# .gitignore and git rm --cached wont keep files from being tracked

Tags: git

I have an android project that has a test module that will remove and recreate .apk files in a  subdirectory in the git directory.

I have added these to .gitignore (the directory, the files explicitly, and *.apk ) and then I have done

```
git rm -r --cached src/main/Tests/bin
```

and git tells me:

```
rm 'src/main/Tests/bin/Tests-debug-unaligned.apk'
rm 'src/main/Tests/bin/Tests-debug.apk'
rm 'src/main/Tests/bin/Tests.ap_'
rm 'src/main/Tests/bin/classes.dex'
```

i then

```
git commit . -m "removed apk files"
```

I run the tests again which delete the files and the recreate them.  I run git status and they show up as modified.  It seems .gitignore is not working.  Here is my .gitignore file

```
*ipr
*iml
*iws
.gitignore
out/
*apk
src/main/Tests/bin
src/main/Tests/bin/*
src/main/Tests/bin/Tests-debug-unaligned.apk
```

Comment: is that because you haven't added to them to .gitignore after you have removed them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your recipe and it worked for me.

```
~ % mkdir deleteme
~ % cd deleteme
~/deleteme % mkdir src src/main src/main/Tests src/main/Tests/bin
~/deleteme % touch src/main/Tests/bin/blah.apk                   
~/deleteme % git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/sri/deleteme/.git/
~/deleteme (master*) % touch src/main/hello.txt
~/deleteme (master*) % git add .
~/deleteme (master*) % git commit -m "init"
[master (root-commit) 0ef5764] init
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 src/main/Tests/bin/blah.apk
 create mode 100644 src/main/hello.txt
~/deleteme (master) % vi .gitignore
~/deleteme (master) % git rm -r --cached src/main/Tests/bin
rm 'src/main/Tests/bin/blah.apk'
~/deleteme (master*) % git commit -m "removed"
[master 5ca6456] removed
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 src/main/Tests/bin/blah.apk
~/deleteme (master) % touch src/main/Tests/bin/blah.apk    
~/deleteme (master) % git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
~/deleteme (master) %
```

Perhaps the gitconfig in some other directory (or a global directive) that's overriding what you have in the gitconfig you have stated.  You did not mention **where** this gitconfig is located.  See the man page for gitignore or the online help docs for the precedence of the various locations where you can specify ignore rules.  The man pages say...

> ...the following order of
>          precedence, from highest to lowest (within one level of precedence, the last matching
>          pattern decides the outcome):
>   Patterns read from the command line for those commands that support
>   them.
>
> ```
>    o   Patterns read from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the path, or in any
>        parent directory, with patterns in the higher level files (up to the toplevel of the
>        work tree) being overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory
>        containing the file. These patterns match relative to the location of the .gitignore
>        file. A project normally includes such .gitignore files in its repository, containing
>        patterns for files generated as part of the project build.
>
>    o   Patterns read from $GIT_DIR/info/exclude.
>
>    o   Patterns read from the file specified by the configuration variable core.excludesfile
> ```

Answer (score 29):

I think you need to clean all your stagged files using:

```
git rm -r --cached .

git add -A
```

Then commit:

```
git commit -m ".gitignore"
```

But make sure you commit your changes before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just

```
*.apk
```

in your .gitignore? If they were tracked before, you will need to delete them and commit that before setting the .gitignore. Once they are out, add the entry in the .gitignore file and it should work.

Comment: i commit the deletes of the files.  I know it then "should work", however it does not.

Comment: *apk as well as the directory they are in and one absolute path just for good measure, same result

Comment: clean up the .gitignore file to not have any .apk entries. Commit. Delete the apk files. git add -A and commit. Just add *.apk to the ignore file. commit. you should now be ignoring the files properly. You can squash all this clean up work into one commit by doing a git reset --soft head~3 && git add -A && git commit -m "fixed ignore"