# Ignoring naughty files with git rebase

Tags: git, gitignore, rebase

I have a GitHub repo where I keep mainly `.tex` files, with Makefiles that compile all of the files to create `.pdf`s. On this repo, the `.gitignore` file serves to ignore some compilation files related to this, most notably the `.pdf`s themselves. Now I also have some files that aren't the result of compiling the `.tex` files, and should therefore not be ignored by `git`. I recently added some code (using the `minted` package) in my `.tex` files that creates compilation files of two certain types, namely `.pygstyle` and `.pygtex`. These files are files I don't want to keep in the repo, hence I added them to my `.gitignore`--after already adding them in a previous commit :(.

I'd like to find the commands I'd have to type in order to rebase this branch in a way that doesn't remove all files in the `.gitignore` from source control, seen as there are some `.pdf`s that I'd like to keep, but the compilation files I mentioned above should be ignored.

I tried rebasing the normal way, only to find out about those lost files that couldn't be ignored; ever since, I've been aimlessly rebasing onto new branches, with little to no success.

Ideally, there would be a way to retroactively apply the `.gitignore` file to the commits introducing the "naughty files", without removing other files that were manually added to bypass the `.gitignore`.

I thought about not using rebase (for example by simply applying the `.gitignore` to a subset of all the files), but I'd like to keep it clean and use `git rebase` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter history based on gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463687/how-to-filter-history-based-on-gitignore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your naughty files are small, I would suggest simply `git rm`ing them and committing the results. From that point on, `.gitignore` will work as you want, since the files will no longer exist in the commits you'll be working on.

If your naughty files are large, you can use `git filter-branch` to rewrite the history without those files. This question will help if you chose this route: [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

For a bit of additional information, the `.gitignore` file only affects what happens in a `git add` and in operations that compare the current state of your sandbox with the current commit. When you rebase, you're asking Git to reapply a given commit with the files and patches it has, as is (by default). You have to edit the commit to remove a file out of it, and the question linked in the previous paragraph explains how to do that manually or via `git filter-branch`.